# How can I select ROI in a separate image in opencv-python?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, roi

I'm using python 2.7.13 and opencv 3.4.0.
I have a videostream with 2 green dots. I'm tracking them using color detection. I need to select a two ROIs(region of interest), each of which will contain one dot, in two separate images for further processing.
I wrote a program which detects them and creates ROIs, but problem is that it selects only one region, while there are two dots. 
Also, it gives me error: 
"line 47, in 
    cv2.imshow ("area1",area1)
NameError: name 'area1' is not defined"

But if I replace img=frame.array line with img=cv2.imread("image.jpg") then it works but only with picture.
[Here how program works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWKSr.png)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import sys

lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255]) #ranges for green color

camera = PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
camera.resolution = (320, 240)
camera.framerate = 30
font=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(320, 240))

time.sleep(0.1)
kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",         use_video_port=True): # capture frames from the camera
    img = frame.array #works only if I change this with img =cv2.imread("image.jpg")
    imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)

    maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
    maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose) #apply morphology for greater accuracy
    maskFinal=maskClose
    _, conts, _=cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    for i in range(len(conts)):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        area1=img[y:y+h, x:x+w] #selecting my ROI
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("maskClose",maskClose)
    cv2.imshow("maskOpen",maskOpen)
    cv2.imshow("mask",mask)
    cv2.imshow("cam",img)
    cv2.imshow ("area1",area1) #Showing my ROI

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    rawCapture.truncate(0)
    if key == ord("q"):
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the for loop you keep setting/overwriting `area1`, so the output will always be just one image. You can solve this easily by moving the imshow() into the for loop.

At the top of your code add:
`prevNrOfContours = 0`

Alter the frame-loop with this code:

```
    # create a window for each roi
    nrOfContours = len(conts)
    for i in range(nrOfContours):
        x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
        area=img[y:y+h, x:x+w] #selecting my ROI
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
        cv2.imshow("area" + str(i), area)

    # if there are more open windows then roi's
    # then close the windows that will not be refreshed
    if prevNrOfContours > nrOfContours:
        for i in range(nrOfContours, prevNrOfContours):
            cv2.destroyWindow("area" + str(i))

    # store the number of roi's in this frame, so it can 
    # be used in the next frame
    prevNrOfContours = nrOfContours
```

Edit: extended code to remove unnecessary opened windows

Edit2: to only select the 2 largest contours:

```
    # instantiate list
    contour_list = []

    for cnt in contours:
            # get contour size
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            # add tuple of the contour and its size to the list
            contour_list.append((cnt, area))

    # sort list on size
    sorted_list = sorted(contour_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
    # create a window for the 2 largest contours
    for i in range(-2,0):
            x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(sorted_list[i][0])
            roi=img[y:y+h, x:x+w] #selecting my ROI
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
            cv2.imshow("area" + str(i), roi)
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot!
It works fine but if you place an object appears in the frame and then disappears, then there remains a window with the last image of this object. How can I destroy such windows automatically?
[Here's how it looks like](https://imgur.com/a/VR6vLrd)

Comment: You can use the function cv2.destroyWindow(window_name) ([documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga851ccdd6961022d1d5b4c4f255dbab34)). I've modified the answer to include this.

Comment: Thank you again,
I extended my program so now it counts number of pixels in each ROI:


`for i in range(len(conts)):
            x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[i])
            area=img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            pixNum = cv2.inRange(area,lowerBound,upperBound )
            no_black = cv2.countNonZero(pixNum)

            cv2.imshow("area" + str(i), area)
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)
            print (no_black)`

Comment: But I keep getting some false ROIs due to glare on the camera, which pop up as windows and heavily load the system. 
How can I get only two ROIs with the biggest pixel number? I also want program show only windows with this 2 ROIs.

Comment: I updated the answer with a possible implementation